# How to debug why python file wont run in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, digital-ocean

Code beneath works great locally. However it does not run in production mode

- DigitalOcean droplet, Nginx/Gunicorn on Ubuntu
- Only difference is path to file

```
# views.py
from django.conf import settings

        base_dir = settings.BASE_DIR
        out = run(['/usr/bin/python3', os.path.join(base_dir, '/myprojectenv/Script.py'), inp], shell=False, stdout=PIPE, text=True)

        logging.debug(out)
        logging.debug(out.check_returncode())
```

In order to debug production server i use.

```
# settings.py
LOGGING = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "root": {"level": "NOTSET", "handlers": ["file"]},

    "handlers": {
        "file": {
            "level": "NOTSET",
            "class": "logging.FileHandler",
            "filename": "/var/log/nginx/django.log",
            "formatter": "app",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        "django": {
            "handlers": ["file"],
            "level": "NOTSET",
            "propagate": True
        },
    },
    "formatters": {
        "app": {
            "format": (
                u"%(asctime)s [%(levelname)-8s] "
                "(%(module)s.%(funcName)s) %(message)s"
            ),
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
        },
    },
}
```

Django.log returns.

```
#django.log
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', 'webapp/myprojectenv/Script.py', 'XXXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX.png']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
2021-01-02 14:24:29 [ERROR   ] (log.log_response) Internal Server Error: /api/auth/upload/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/webapp/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/webapp/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/webapp/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapp/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapp/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/webapp/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/webapp/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/webapp/myprojectenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/webapp/app/views.py", line 43, in post
    out = run(['/usr/bin/python3', os.path.join(base_dir, 'myprojectenv/Script.py'), inp], shell=False,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 512, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/usr/bin/python3', 'webapp/myprojectenv/Script.py', 'XXXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX.png']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Returncode 1 (A syntax error is returned). Not sure what i am doing wrong.  How can i debug this further? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using double forward slash in path name? Try using the full path of the location where you have the script. To find the full path go to the location of the script and type `pwd`.

Comment: Bad habit. Double slash is ignored and creates a normal "/". the full path seems to be the same as written above "/mywebapp/myprojectenv/Script.py". I have also tried this path with no results "os.path.abspath('/mywebapp/myprojectenv/Script.py")

Comment: Are you using linux based droplet? **mywebapp** is in root directory?

Comment: I'm using Nginx and Gunicorn. Maybe the path is correct but i need to allow scripts to be able to be run somehow? Not sure what i'm missing.

Comment: Ubuntu. mywebapp is the root directory. I also attempted "out = run([sys.executable, os.path.join(base_dir, 'myprojectenv/Script.py'),inp],shell=False,stdout=PIPE, text= True)" which shows no errors in the debug.log and prints as '/mywebapp/myprojectenv/Script.py'.... I have also added a "logging.debug("Is Script running?") command to trigger if script would run. Nothing returns so far. –